# Producing a sawtooth signal out of square/triangular signal

Tags: signals, comparator, integrator

I want to create a sawtooth signal generator. I know, how to build comparator to create a square wave. I allso know, how i can get triangular signal by integrating comparator output with o amp integrator.

What i don't know nor find is how do i get sawtooth signal out of square/triangular wave. Could someone explain this a bit.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

Start with a square wave with period T. Differentiate it to produce spikes, alternating positive and negative. Use *those* to reset an integrator that integrates a DC signal. This will produce a sawtooth wave with period T/2.

If you want a sawtooth wave with period T, knock out the negative spikes with a diode.

Answer (score 0):

Integrate the absolute value of the square wave; every time the square wave goes from high to low, reset the integrator.

Comment: How can i achieve absolute value of a square wave?

Comment: @71GA: Most languages have an `abs` function (or similar).

Comment: I am doing this in analog way so what kind of electric circuit is needed here?

Comment: Wouldn't this give a sawtooth wave with every other tooth missing?

Comment: @71GA: Stack Overflow is for programming questions; if you need an electronics solution then you need to ask at http://electronics.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Beta: I don't think so.

Comment: Wanna bet? The square waves I know spend half their time high, half low. (There are variants, but they take extra work to synth, and they aren't called "square waves"-- maybe it's a transatlantic thing.) If we set "low" to zero (and we'd better) then for half the cycle the output wave will climb in a nice saw tooth, and for the other half it'll be flat.

Comment: @Beta: Oh, what I meant was that you reset on the transition.

Comment: Ah, I didn't catch the meaning of the intent of the absolute value. I assumed the square wave alternated between +V and 0, where you assumed it alternated between +V and -V.